# Why is my storyboard segue triggering before a line of code before it executes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm transitioning between my game's main menu and the game itself, and am in need of a loading screen. The current behavior is that I tap the Play button, and there's no movement and no segue for a few seconds, then the game begins.

Temporarily, I'm just throwing up a `UIActivityIndicatorView` and manually telling it to `startAnimating`, then calling the segue to the other scene. The issue is that code from the game view (the end-point of the segue) is being run before the view has physically changed on-screen (i.e. I'm seeing the menu while code from the game is being executed). I don't quite see how this happens, since the spinner is told to display before the segue is called. Here's the code:

```
- (IBAction) startGame: (id) sender
{
    [_loadingView setHidden: NO];
    [_loadingSpinner startAnimating];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"PlayGame" sender: self];
}
```

The stuff that's actually taking the time isn't called until the segue has completed (i.e. until the game's main view is shown onscreen in an entirely different `ViewController` (it's querying an SQLite database)), so why is the spinner not showing until after that work has been done? Should I be using GCD or similar for this? I've done a little experimenting with it but it might be a tad above my level at present. The heavy code is contained in one method, so I'd ideally like to be able to do something like this, literally executing the lines in order.

```
[spinner startAnimating];
[self callMethodThatTakesAges];
[spinner stopAnimating];
```

I've tried using `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`, but it seems to be getting confused between the two views. The spinner should show on the game view, not the menu view, ideally, so I should tap Play, the transition to the game view should be instant, then the spinner should appear, loading should start, spinner should vanish when done.

Any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT: Here are some methods from my game view controller (`makeNewWord` is the troublesome method).

```
- (void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL) animated
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [spinner setCenter: CGPointMake(240, 55)];
    [self.view addSubview: spinner];
    [spinner startAnimating];
    [self makeNewWord];
    [spinner stopAnimating];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];

}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self canBecomeFirstResponder];

    firstLetterMultiplierLetter = [[NSString alloc] init];
    userIsEnteringAWord = NO;

    [self setUpGestures];
}
```

Here's the method called from my main menu view that segues into the game view:

```
- (IBAction) startGame: (id) sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"PlayGame" sender: self];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you have where from your question.  I would say you want to do this:

```
1) add the spinner to the game view 
2) in game view viewDidAppear, have [spinner startAnimating];
3) call [self methodThatTakesAges] (as the next line in viewDidAppear).
4) call [spinner stopAnimating] from whatever call back method you have in methodThatTakesAges
```

The only thing in your startGame: method should be the performSegue line. You might also need to change where you start the download to where I said, it's not clear where you're starting that now.

Comment: The issue with doing it that way is that I don't actually see the next view until the `methodThatTakesAges` has finished. It sticks on the main menu, with the Play button, in a highlighted state, while it loads, then loads the game view afterward. It needs to load that view before it starts processing the long method, but I'm not sure quite how to insist that it does that.

Comment: @lukech, you do it like I said in my answer - don't call the method that takes time until viewDidLoad in game view. Is there some reason you can't do it that way? Where are you starting the download now?

Comment: I'm already doing that! That's exactly where it is called. I click Play on the `MainMenuView`, which triggers a segue to `GameView`, and in the `viewDidLoad` in `GameView`, the heavy-duty method is called. But, for some reason, clicking that Play button in `MainMenuView` doesn't even show the `GameView` until that heavy method has finished. Sorry if I'm not explaining clearly :)

Comment: @lukech, sorry I wrote the wrong thing in my comment -- in my answer I said to do that in viewDidAppear. Try moving it there, and see if that helps.

Comment: No difference, I'm afraid. I still sit and look at the pushed Play button on the menu, and the game view loads when the long method has finished, not before.

Comment: @lukech, I can't help any more without seeing some code. You should edit your question to show at least the viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear methods of the game view controller.

Comment: I've added those methods, hopefully that helps.

Comment: @lukech, I have two suggestions. Try moving the spinner stuff to viewWillAppear, leaving the call to makeNewWord in viewDidAppear. Or, put a performSelector:WithObject:afterDelay: method in viewDidAppear, and call makeNewWord in its selector instead of in viewDidAppear.

Comment: Looks like the former of those last two suggestions worked. Thanks very much for sticking with me! :)